# Generate custom xml from jasper reports

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I want to generate the xml output from jxml file using japser report. I have to achieve something like this.

```
<xml>
    <header>
        <type />
    </header>
    <members>
        <info />
        <info />
        <data atrr="df">
            <name></name>
            <city></city>
        </data>
        <data atrr="df">
            <name></name>
            <city></city>
        </data>
        <data atrr="df">
            <name></name>
            <city></city>
        </data>
    </members>
    </xml>
```

But I am getting output like this.

```
 <jasperPrint xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperprint.xsd" name="json" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" topMargin="20" leftMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" rightMargin="20" locale="it_IT" timezone="Asia/Kolkata"><property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.start.page.index" value="0"/><property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.end.page.index" value="0"/><property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.page.count" value="1"/>
<origin band="background"/><origin band="pageHeader"/>
<origin band="columnHeader"/><origin band="detail"/>
<origin band="columnFooter"/><origin band="pageFooter"/>
<origin band="summary"/>
<page><text textHeight="11.640625" lineSpacingFactor="1.1640625" leadingOffset="-2.3583984">
<reportElement uuid="698866c8-7d26-4bc7-8727-b4a56d239a53" x="92" y="50" width="100" height="24" origin="3" srcId="1" printId="1"/>
<textContent>b1</textContent>
</text><text textHeight="11.640625" lineSpacingFactor="1.1640625" leadingOffset="-2.3583984">
<reportElement uuid="e775c6c0-4058-4bc4-8c7a-d4d381fd6e66" x="210" y="50" width="100" height="24" origin="3" srcId="2" printId="1"/>
<textContent>b2</textContent></text>
 ......
```

As I want result as plain xml and I am getting result which contains the jasperrprint tags means elements of jrxml file.

Is it possible to achieve normal xml?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can not. Why do want jasper to generate normal xml ?

Comment: I am trying to develop generic functionality using jasper where I want to generate output in PDF/XML/xls using the jrxml as templates.

Comment: `Is it possible to achieve normal xml?` - *JRXmlExporter* generates "normal" valid *xml*. You can always perform transformation. You can create your own Exporter (with your schema and rules)

Comment: IMHO, it is not a best idea to generate *xml* with JasperReports

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for your reply. I am looking for another solution for the same.

Comment: @RupeshPatil use the JAXB for xml preperation